# Extract text before first \sx\s with regex

Tags: regex

I have text like this:

```
#12222223334 x $32.97
```

I want to extract the last number of the number before the "x" for example in this case the number 4.

Another example: `#8885555889 x $33.33`. Here, the number I want is 9.

I tried `^(.+?) x`, but its all the number before the `x`.

Comment: Why not just `\d(?=\s*x)`? What is the regex flavor?

Answer (score 1):

this also gets you the last digits before the space and x

https://regex101.com/r/zVevtY/1

```
(\d)\s?x

# (\d) : capture a digit
# \s? : before a possible white space
# x : followed by literal x
```

Comment: consider accepting the answer, that worked for you  @omrihamo

Answer (score 0):

If your regex engine support lookaheads, you may use:

```
\d(?=\s*x\s+\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?$)
```

### Demo

This pattern says to match:

- `\d` a single digit
- `(?=` assert that what follows (but do not match)

  - `\s*x\s+` x
  - `\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?` followed by a currency amount
  - `$` end of the string
- `)` end lookahead